# Timestamp to xsd:base64Binary in XML Schema

Tags: xml, xsd, timestamp

Why in [this](http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/sqltypes/SqlTypes.xsd) xsd schema Timestamp type has length 8 characters?

```
<xsd:simpleType name="timestamp">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:base64Binary">
    <xsd:maxLength value="8"/>
</xsd:restriction>
```

I think that length should be 12 characters.

Example:
0x00000000000007D1 -> AAAAAAAAB9E=

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The maxLength facet for a base64Binary value is the maximum number of octets in the binary value, not the maximum number of characters in the lexical representation.